# Spring Batch: what is an expected behavior for chunk attribute?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, rabbitmq, spring-batch

Example of Step configuration that I have:

```
Step employersStep = stepBuilderFactory.get("employersStep")
        .<Employer, EmployerEntity>chunk(10)
        .reader(amqpReader())
        .processor(processor)
        .writer(entityWriter)
        .build();
```

as you may see I am trying:

- Read data from AMQP broker (`RabbitMQ`);
- process it;
- write processed data to DB.

What is the expected behavior for case:

when only 1 message available in queue?

Will it be consumed, processed and stored in DB or `Spring Batch` will wait till `10` (chunk size that specified above) messages become available in the queue?

*The reason why I ask:*

I wrote the test where send 1 message to `RabbitMQ` and see that `Spring Batch` processor and writer successfully executed.

Than I replaced `RabbitMQ` by `Kafka` rerun the test and found that `Spring Batch` doesn't do anything when `Kafka` topic contains <10 messages and executes processor and writer when >10 messages available in the topic.
So, the behavior is absolutely different and I need to know which one is correct to start troubleshooting.

Answer (score 1):

You should have different timeout values on the rabbit reader and kafka reader to see this difference in behavior. The step implementation itself is the same no matter the reader you use. In its most basic form, a chunk-oriented step is implemented as follows:

```
Chunk<T> chunk = chunkProvider.provide() // delegates to item reader
chunkProcessor.process(chunk); // delegates to item processor + writer
```

So as you can see, the step will accumulate items in memory by calling `ItemReader#read` until `chunkSize` is reached or the item reader returns `null` (to signal that the dataset is exhausted). Now when this method returns `null`  depends on the timeout you set on the reader. But in both cases, the `ChunkProcessor` (processor and writer) won't be called until a chunk is ready.